# How to add a default "where" clause to a child class?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My question is as follows, I have an interface SportInterface.php as follows:

```
interface SportInterface
{
    public function fetchFixtures($date_from, $date_to, $page);
    public function updateOdds($fixture_id, $market_id = null);
    public function updateOdd($fixture_id, $market_id, $data);
}
```

And I also have a "Sport model" which is as follows:

```
class Sport extends Model implements SportInterface
{
}
```

And I have a Football model which is as follows:

```
class Football extends Sport
{

}
```

Now my question is, I wanted the Football model to use the database table "sports", however - I want a default where claus, Example, instead of doing this:

```
$football = Sport::where('sport','football')->where('id',3000)->first();
```

I want to do:

```
$football = Football::where('id',3000)->first();
```

Any tips? thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can surely use [global scope](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#global-scopes) add a default where clause to every query.